# How to use login ID session variable in Oracle BI publisher report

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I am thinking of setting user filter on report. So user can only see data related to him.

It is supposed to login to Oracle bi publisher， then open report， and the related data will show up.

Is there a way to extract login id as parameter in a data model?

Database is from DB2

Answer (score 0):

There are user information stored in system variables that you can include in your data model. The folowing query would give you the user info that you can refference in your report:

```sql
select
  :xdo_user_name as USER_ID,
  :xdo_user_roles as USER_ROLES,
  :xdo_user_report_oracle_lang as REPORT_LANGUAGE,
  :xdo_user_report_locale as REPORT_LOCALE,
  :xdo_user_ui_oracle_lang as UI_LANGUAGE,
  :xdo_user_ui_locale as UI_LOCALE
from dual
```

More about it at: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPDM/GUID-2A6E4B9B-ABCD-4CF0-A458-59B89F2443A1.htm#BIPDM223
Regards...